# Is there a way to inject a featured image field in mezzanine / django RichTextPage model?

Tags: django, mezzanine

Is there a way to **inject a featured image field** in Mezzanine / Django RichTextPage's model? I need get a image, to specific pages in "richtextpage.html" template, but these are different from blogPost models that have a featured image field.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED] The problem: I was trying to register/unregister a new field in Page model instead RichTextPage, changing the references got the expected result;

```
# settings.py

EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS = (
(
    "mezzanine.pages.models.Page.page_image",
    "ImageField",
    ("Featured Image",),
    {"blank": True, "upload_to": "uploads", },
), ...

# application admin.py

from copy import deepcopy
from mezzanine.pages.admin import PageAdmin
from mezzanine.pages.models import RichTextPage
(...)

pages_fieldsets = deepcopy(PageAdmin.fieldsets)
pages_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(-2, "page_image")
pages_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(-3, "content")

class CustomPageAdmin(PageAdmin):
    fieldsets = pages_fieldsets


admin.site.unregister(RichTextPage)
admin.site.register(RichTextPage, CustomPageAdmin)
```